# How to import identifier from startup.s (to main.c)

Tags: arm, iar

I would like to locate a table of constant values with application data (equipment information), preferably at the end of the vector table.

In `startup.s` I do the following:

```
    MODULE  ?cstartup

    ;; Forward declaration of sections.
    SECTION CSTACK:DATA:NOROOT(3)

    SECTION .intvec:CODE:NOROOT(2)

    EXTERN  __iar_program_start
    EXTERN  SystemInit        
    PUBLIC  __vector_table

    PUBLIC  _InfoEqData

    DATA
    __vector_table

    DCD     sfe(CSTACK)
    DCD     Reset_Handler             ; Reset Handler

    /* ............... */

    DCD     LCD_IRQHandler                 ; LCD
    DCD     USB_IRQHandler                 ; USB
    __vector_table_end

    _InfoEqData     EQU     __vector_table_end
```

In `main.c` I do the following:

```
#pragma location = _InfoEqData
const EqIdentify_t  eqIdentify = { ... }
```

When I compile the code shows the following (expected) error

```
Error[Pe020]: identifier "_InfoEqData" is undefined ... \tst_vBus_main.cpp 25
```

How do I tell the compiler to find that identifier from `startup.s`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IAR toolchain supports `#pragma location`<sup>1</sup> only to fix data at absolute addresses given by literal numbers<sup>2</sup> or segment names<sup>3</sup>.

From my point of view, you should define an own segment in the linker command file<sup>3</sup> and locate it according to your requirements.

---

<sup>1</sup>
[IAR C/C++ Compiler User Guide for the 8051Microcontroller Architecture (C8051-7)](http://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/8051/webic/doc/EW8051_CompilerGuide.pdf), Seventh edition: March 2017, page 372.

<sup>2</sup>
[*ibid.*](http://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/8051/webic/doc/EW8051_CompilerGuide.pdf), Seventh edition: March 2017, page 260.

<sup>3</sup>
[*ibid.*](http://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/8051/webic/doc/EW8051_CompilerGuide.pdf), Seventh edition: March 2017, page 262.

<sup>4</sup>
[IAR Linker and Library Tools Reference Guide (XLINK-5001)](http://supp.iar.com/filespublic/updinfo/005664/xlink.pdf), April 2010, page 21.

Comment: OK thank you very much.
I will follow your suggestion.
Regards